# Triangular inequality for integrals

Tags: integration

I know that if $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$, having $\left|\int_a^bf \right| = \int_a^b|f|$ is equivalent to sign of $f$ constant over $[a,b]$. When $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{C}$, what does it mean ?

Also, does this change when I integrate over a measure which isn't Lebesgue ?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: To each complex number $w$ there is some $\varphi \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|w|=e^{i\varphi}w$. Try to apply this to $w = \int_a^b f$.

Comment: If I write $w = \int_a^bf = re^{i\theta}$, I have $|w| = r = we^{-i\theta} = \int_a^bfe^{-i\theta}$ and since $r$ is real, positive, $|w| = |\Re(\int_a^b f^{-i\theta}) |  = |\int_a^b\Re(fe^{-i\theta})|\leq \int_a^b|\Re(fe^{-i\theta})|\leq \int_a^b|f|.$ Thus I have equality in the first triangular (real) inequality and $\Re(fe^{-i\theta})$ is of constant sign. But what more ?

Comment: I guess I also have that $|\Re(fe^{-i\theta})| = |f|$, and thus $\Im(fe^{-i\theta}) = 0$ and $fe^{-i\theta} = \Re(fe^{-i\theta}) = |f|$, meaning that $f = e^{i\theta}|f|$ and $f$ is of constant argument. That seems right

Comment: Yes,  I think that's right. There is one typo $f^{-i\theta}$ should be $f e^{-i\theta}$.

Comment: $\frac{f}{|f|}$ should be constant along the integral region. 
This covers both the real and complex case.